# A simple git_status to prompt

Tags: beginner, algorithm, bash, git

The following bash script was made to retrieve some local repository information in order to be used to display a condensed `git status` in terminal PS1 prompt.

It performs some simple greps over (`git status`) `--short` version text to display 6 repository status: **Commits ahead, commits behind, added files, modifiled files, untracked files and deleted files**

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $(find .git 2> /dev/null | wc -l) > 0 ]]; then

        local branch="$(git branch | grep '*' | cut -d ' ' -f 2)"
        local remote="$(git remote)/$branch"
        local status=""

        # Commits ahead
        local ahead=$(git rev-list --count $remote..$branch)
        [[ $ahead > 0 ]] && status="$status ⭑$ahead"
        # Commits behind
        local behind=$(git rev-list --count $branch..$remote)
        [[ $behind > 0 ]] && status="$status !$behind"
        # Added files
        A=$(git status -s | grep -Pc "^[RAM]..")
        [[ $A > 0 ]] && status="$status +$A"
        # Modifiled files
        M=$(git status -s | grep -Pc "^.M.")
        [[ $M > 0 ]] && status="$status ~$M"
        # Untracked files
        U=$(git status -s | grep -c "?? ")
        [[ $U > 0 ]] && status="$status ·$U"
        # Deleted files
        D=$(git status -s | grep -Pc "^.D.")
        [[ $D > 0 ]] && status="$status -$D"

        echo "$branch$status"
    fi
```

By now, I'm actually using this code inside a `.bashrc` function and, accordingly calling it through my PS1 variable:

[image]

It would be nice to receive some code review about `grep` and `git` usage, `bash` organization, syntax, readability and other improvements. I'm also interested in best practices over have function calls from PS1.